# How to pull one event from an observable when another emits

Tags: swift, rx-swift, reactivex

I can't work out how to pull one event from an observable when another fires (at least, I think that's the essence of the problem but I'm so confused I might be wrong).

I have a ViewModel which is passed an array of objects on initialisation. The corresponding ViewController shows one of those objects at a time for the user to accept or decline (two buttons), along with an option to apply the response to all remaining objects (a checkbox). A side-effect of accepting the object (and possibly all remaining ones) is a database insertion. When there are no more objects the ViewController will be dismissed.

How can I model this reactively (using RxSwift/Cocoa)?

I'd also like to be able to show the user how many objects are remaining but that seems like an additional complexity.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any code you can share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example implementation for the described behaviour.

*Remember though that stackoverflow is not meant to work like this. You should show the code that you wrote to try to solve your problem first.*

```
// This encodes a database action. You can subscribe to view model's `dbAction` to perform your desired side effect.
enum DBAction<T> {
    case insert(object: T)
    case delete(object: T)
}

class SomeViewModel<Object> {
    struct Output {
        let currentObject: Observable<Object>
        let remainingObjectCount: Observable<Int>
        let dbAction: Observable<DBAction<Object>>
    }

    struct Input {
        let acceptOrDecline: Observable<(keepOrDrop: Bool, applyToAll: Bool)>
    }

    let totalObjectCount: Int
    let objects: Observable<Object>

    init(objects: [Object]) {
        self.totalObjectCount = objects.count
        self.objects = .from(objects) // 1
    }

    func transform(input: Input) -> Output {
        let applyToAll: Observable<Void> = input.acceptOrDecline.map { $0.applyToAll }.filter { $0 == true }.map { _ in }
        let acceptOrDecline = input.acceptOrDecline.map { $0.keepOrDrop }

        let currentObject = Observable.zip( // 2
            objects,
            acceptOrDecline.map { _ in }.startWith() // 3
        ) { object, _ in object }
            .takeUntil(applyToAll) // 4
            .share()

        // 5
        let actionForCurrent = input.acceptOrDecline.flatMap { tuple in
            tuple.applyToAll ? Observable.repeatElement(tuple.keepOrDrop, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance) : .just(tuple.keepOrDrop)
        }

        let dbAction = Observable.zip(
            objects,
            actionForCurrent
        ) { (object: Object, shouldKeep: Bool) -> DBAction<Object> in
            if shouldKeep {
                return DBAction.insert(object: object)
            } else {
                return DBAction.delete(object: object)
            }
        }

        let remainingObjectCount = currentObject.scan(totalObjectCount) { acc, _ in
            acc - 1
        }.concat(.just(0))

        return Output(
            currentObject: currentObject,
            remainingObjectCount: remainingObjectCount,
            dbAction: dbAction
        )
    }
}
```

1. Here I create an obversable that will emit each elements in the source array, on after the other.
2. [zip](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html) combines elements from two observables. The good thing with zip is that it will wait for a distinct element from each source. When subscribing to the result of zip, a new element will be emitted after `input.acceptOrDecline` emits. Hence, we'll receive a new object after each decision.
3. `startWith()` will force a first emission, so that we receive the first object we want the user to take a decision on.
4. `takeUntil` will make our observable complete when `applyToAll` emits. So that we do not receive a new element when the `applyToAll` checkbox is checked.
5. `repeatElement` will indefinitely repeat an element. So when `applyToAll` is true, we'll repeat the decision indefinitely. Because we zip the result of `flatMap` to `objects`, it will repeat the decision for the number of remaning object in `objects`.

---

To build the source observable for the view model, assuming you are using two `UIButton`s and a `UISwitch`

```
let acceptButton: UIButton
let dropButton: UIButton
let applyToAll: UISwitch

let accept = acceptButton.rx.tap.map { true }
let drop = dropButton.rx.tap.map { false }
let input = Input(
    acceptOrDecline: Observable.combineLatest(
        Observable.merge(accept, drop),
        applyToAll.rx.value
    ) { (keepOrDrop: $0, applyToAll: $1) }
)
```

**Note** that this is a proposed implementation that compiles but that I did not test. You'll find here leads to implement your desired behavior, but I cannot guaranty this is 100% correct.